# Realm db DynamicRealmObject not valid during migration

Tags: android, kotlin, realm, illegalstateexception, realm-migration

I've been working with Realm for well over a year so I'm not new to the whole migration flow but this has me scratching my head for several days:

During a data migration to a new schema version I need to create some objects and insert them to the DB, and later connect them to another type of objects.

First I create a map of the dynamic objects so I could connect them to the second type later:

```
    val generatedStoreVisitTypes = mutableMapOf<String, DynamicRealmObject>()
```

Then I create and use the dynamicObjects:

```
fun migrateToVersion19(realm: DynamicRealm) {

    // an extension method I created which adds the field if it doesn’t exist already, impl at the bottom
    realm.schema.getOrCreate<RealmMetadata>()
        // an extension method I created which adds the field if it doesn’t exist already, impl at the bottom
        .safeAddRealmListField(RealmMetadata::storeVisitTypes, realm.schema)
        .transform { metadata ->
            // I use the string name of the property here and not reflection since this field is deleted during this migration
            val currentStoreTaskList = metadata.getList("storeTasks")
            currentStoreTaskList.forEach { storeTasks ->
                // create an instance here and initialise it
                val visitTypeTasks = realm.createObject(MetaVisitTypeTasks::class.java.simpleName)
                visitTypeTasks[MetaVisitTypeTasks::visitTypeId.name] = "1"
                val visitTasks = visitTypeTasks.getList(MetaVisitTypeTasks::visitTasks.name)
                storeTasks.getList("storeTasks").forEach {
                    visitTasks.add(it)
                }

                // save the object to the map
                generatedStoreVisitTypes[storeUid] = visitTypeTasks
                }
            }
            .safeRemoveField("storeTasks")

        realm.schema.getOrCreate<RealmStore>()
        .safeAddRealmListField(RealmStore::visitTypes, realm.schema)
        .transform {
            val storeUid = it.getString(RealmStore::storeUid.name)
            // crash here on the “add” method
            it.getList(RealmStore::visitTypes.name).add(generatedStoreVisitTypes[storeUid])
        }
    }
}

private inline fun <reified T> RealmSchema.getOrCreate(): RealmObjectSchema {
    return get(T::class.java.simpleName) ?: create(T::class.java.simpleName)
}

private inline fun <reified TClass : RealmObject, reified TListItem : RealmObject, reified TList : RealmList<TListItem>> RealmObjectSchema.safeAddRealmListField(addedField: KMutableProperty1<TClass, TList>, schema: RealmSchema): RealmObjectSchema {
    val fieldName = addedField.name
    val listItemObjectSchema = schema.get(TListItem::class.java.simpleName)

    if (!hasField(fieldName)) {
        return addRealmListField(fieldName, listItemObjectSchema)
    }
    return this
}
```

Calling the "add" method in the second “transform” method sometimes causes a -

“java.lang.IllegalStateException: Object is no longer valid to operate on. Was it deleted by another thread?”

I’m familiar with this error and usually know how to handle it but I can’t recreate it or understand how such a thing happens in this case.
Since we’re talking about migration, there shouldn’t be another thread that’s operating on the same schema - as the execution is synchronised, isn’t it?.
Also, we’re talking about an object that was **just created**. There’s no other context in which it’s referenced or used.

I don’t understand how this object could be deleted. What could cause such an error?

Comment: Can't you just create your new schema first, and do migration in the first `transform` function ?

Comment: I'm having a similar issue. Were you using multi process?

Comment: I am also having a similar issue, inside the migration, the objects which are just queried get "invalidated" somehow and I receive "Object is no longer valid to operate on...." when I access them. Note that these objects aren't even created within the migration but just queried, so it might be an issue with my current realm version 6.0 that I am using.